# Jaxb generation of value constructor for a single class

Tags: java, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a collection of XSD's that I am the maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate the java classes.  I have 1 class, that I need a value constructor on, however I do not want value constructors for any of the other generated classes.  I have looked at jaxb-value-constructor-plugin but I don't see a way to specify a single class.

Is there a way to have only a single class generate the value constructor that I am missing or is there another plugin I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just do code injection? See the [code injector plugin](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html).